# PHP show data from Oracle database in a listbox

Tags: php, oracle, listbox

I want to show data from a Oracle database into a listbox.
, but I don't no how to do that.
Now I'm using a textbox and that works good.

This is my HTML code

```
 <form name="form1" method="get" action="Get_opdracht.php"
    Opdrachtnummer: <br /> <input id="Password1" type="number" name="nummer1" required="required"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Zoeken" />
            <hr />
</form>
```

PHP code (get_opdracht.php)

```
// database connect
$conn = oci_connect('username', 'password', 'connect');

// variable textbox
$username = $_GET['nummer1'];

// SELECT query
$array = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM OPD_VW, MDW_VW WHERE OPD_OPDRACHTNUMMER = '$username'");
$query = oci_execute($array);

//show data on page
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($array, OCI_BOTH)) != false) {
    echo "<h1>Opdrachtnummer: " . $row['OPD_OPDRACHTNUMMER'] . "</h1><p> <b>Status: </b>" . $row['OPD_STATUS'] . "<p><b>Registratiedatum: </b>" . $row['OPD_REGISTRATIEDATUM'] . "<p><b>Einddatum: </b>" . $row['OPD_EINDDATUM'] . "<p><b>BTW tarief: </b>". $row['OPD_BTW_TARIEF'] . "<p><b>Totale contractsom: €</b>" . $row['OPD_TOTALE_CONTRACTSOM'] . "<p><b>Percentage gerealiseerd: </b>" . $row['OPD_PERCENTAGE_GEREALISEERD'] . "%";    
    oci_free_statement($array);
    oci_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a listbox you need to use the `select multiple` as shown below.

```
<select name="myselect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="value">OPTION</option>
  <option value="value">OPTION</option>
</select>
```